# How do i left join a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i have my data like this, and i'm trying to get a list of users with a total count of unique activities done and a sum of all the points of unique activities done, so if for eg a user repeats activity 1 3times, it will count as 100 plus what ever other activities etc.

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
SELECT *,
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM done 
     WHERE done.user_id = user.id 
  ) as activity_count
FROM
  user AS user
LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT SUM(points), d.user_id
    FROM done AS d
    LEFT JOIN activity AS a
      ON d.activity_id = a.id
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) AS subtable 
ON  subtable.user_id = user.id
```

My data schema is as such:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `activity` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `points` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `done` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `activity_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `status` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO user
  (`id`, `name`)
  VALUES
   (1, 'User 1'),
   (2, 'User 2'),
   (3, 'User 3'),
   (4, 'User 4');
INSERT INTO activity
   (`id`, `name`, `points`)
  VALUES
   (1, 'activity 1', 100), 
   (2, 'activity 2', 200),
   (3, 'activity 3', 300),
   (4, 'activity 4', 400);
INSERT INTO done
  (`id`, `user_id`, `activity_id`, `status`)
  VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 2),
    (2, 2, 1, 3),
    (3, 1, 2, 2),
    (4, 3, 1, 1),
    (5, 2, 1, 3),
    (6, 4, 4, 2),
    (7, 3, 1, 1),
    (8, 1, 1, 3);
```

Expected results:

```
user_id,   count_of_unique_activities_done, sum_of_unique_activity_points
1,   2,  300;
2,   1,  100;
3,   1,  100;
4,   1,  400;
```

Added a new row in the done table to help illustrate what i need.

Comment: what does `doesn't work` mean?

Comment: if you want unique count, GROUP BY should be used.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: @Ultimater I'm looking for a list of users with something like this, **user id, total count unique activities done, total points of unique activities done**
Will try to edit the question to see if i can add in a sample output i'm expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your query could be simplified as

```
SELECT u.id, SUM(a.points), count(a.*)
FROM `user` u
LEFT JOIN done d ON done.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN activity a ON d.activity_id = a.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: Just a question, does MySQL accept count(a.*)? I have never seen that construction before. What does it mean?

Comment: @jarlh you would count the number of non-null (a.\*). So basically, if the left join hits a row, it's counted. If you said count(\*) or count(1), it would return the number of rows including those with no activities. Similarly if you asked for count(a.points) for instance and an activity has *NULL* for points, it wouldn't be accounted for.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @vkp  when i use (a.*) i get this sql error
   *** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*).*** If i use (*) it's ok. Also the results is not what i want... It's counting the SUM of activity points regardless is that activity is the same... If they are the same for the same user, the points should only be 1 instance, not multiple. For eg, User 2 did activity 1(100points) twice, the result for his points column should be 100, not 200 (Which is what the sql statement is returning)

Comment: Updated my question and added a sample expected result to try to show what i'm trying to get the output to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think i managed to get it to what i want, but is an inefficient statement?

```
SELECT activity_done.id, SUM(activity_done.points) as total_points, user_c.name
FROM
    ( 
        SELECT done_c.user_id as id, points
        FROM 
            done as done_c
        LEFT JOIN
            activity as activity_c
        ON
            activity_c.id = done_c.activity_id
        GROUP BY
            done_c.`activity_id`,
            done_c.`user_id`
    ) as activity_done
LEFT JOIN
    user as user_c
    ON 
        user_c.id = activity_done.id
GROUP BY
    activity_done.id
```